# Don't preserve formatting in cross-reference

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, office365, cross-reference, microsoft-word-365

When I in MS Word 365 create **cross-references**, a **table-of-contents** or an **index**, then any custom formatting I have done on the headlines, bookmarked words etc. *appear in the cross-references*.

For instance, if I have coloured a headline yellow on the page, then that particular headline pops up in yellow in my table-of-contents and in cross-references. The same happens for bold text and possibly more.

[image]

I can manually change the colour and edit other formatting on the cross-reference, of course, but if I ever right click the cross-reference to click "Update field", then the formatting reappears and cancels my manual formatting.

I have tried following this guide: https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/word-remove-formatting-from-cross-references/ where

- I highlight a portion of text which includes some cross-references,
- then right-click,
- click "*Edit field*" and
- then remove the checkmark from "*Preserve formatting during updates*".

This doesn't work and the formatting reappears when "Update field" is click later on.

Am I doing something wrong in relation to what this guide explains? Do anyone have a suggestion for what I am missing?

- Preferably I would like this formatting-preservation functionality removed from the entire document since I will never need the original formatting where the cross-reference is shown.
- Alternatively, I am guessing that I need to do my custom formatting on the headlines and words inside the text in a different manner - because the standard typography on e.g. headlines is not preserved in cross-references, only custom formatting I have added myself. Possibly I need to add such custom formatting in a different manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Most Direct Formatting in the Source Will Be Copied; Style-Based Formatting Will Not

This is discussed in Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's article [TOC Tricks and Tips](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#DirectFormatting).

*(Better in the original)*

> I have said that by default Word’s TOC styles are very plain. If you
> haven’t changed them in any way and you see text that is different,
> then this is coming from your headings. TOC entries do not reflect any
> formatting that is part of a heading style, but they can pick up any
> font formatting that is applied directly. So, for example, if your
> Heading 1 style is defined as 16-point Arial Bold and your Heading 1
> paragraph is 16-point Arial Bold, then the TOC entry for that
> paragraph will still be 12-point Times New Roman or 11-point Calibri.
> But if you change the formatting of part of the heading, making one of
> the words italic, for example, then that change will be reflected in
> the TOC entry.
>
> Usually this is what you want. For example, if your heading includes
> words italicized for emphasis or because they are a book title, you
> will probably want them to be italicized in the TOC as well. Where
> users often get into trouble, however, is with UPPERCASE and All Caps
> formatting.
>
> If you want your Heading 1 paragraphs to be in all caps, you should add All Caps formatting to the Heading 1 style instead of
> typing the headings with Caps Lock on. When you do the latter, then
> the caps are direct formatting (UPPERCASE rather than All Caps), and
> the headings will be capitalized in the TOC as well, which may not be
> what you want (and if it is, you should format TOC 1 as All Caps).
>
> If you have already applied All Caps formatting to a heading style, you may not realize when you are typing a heading that you
> haven’t capitalized some of the words that should be capitalized. When
> you see the TOC entry, which is in Caps & lowercase, you often have to
> go back and correct the typing of the heading itself.
>
> **Important Note:** Not all direct formatting is reflected in the TOC. Paragraph formatting is always ignored. This means that if your
> Heading 1 is defined as 12 points Spacing Before and 3 points Spacing
> After and you modify one Heading 1 paragraph to have 24 points Spacing
> Before, this will not affect the TOC. Only direct font formatting is
> picked up, and not even all of that; here's a rundown:
>
> Font formatting that is picked up by the TOC: the font itself (font name), italics, bold, superscript/subscript,
> strikethrough/double strikethrough, small caps/all caps, hidden,
> raised/lowered, expanded/condensed, scaled.
>
> Font formatting that is NOT picked up by the TOC: font size, font color, underline.
>
> Another important note: The above applies to TOCs in which the entire entry is hyperlinked (that is, the TOC field code includes the
> \h switch). In these TOCs, the Hyperlink character style (which by
> default is blue and underlined) is applied to the entry but
> suppressed. Apparently this results in suppression of underline and
> all colors. If you remove the \h switch (the entry will not be
> hyperlinked, but the page number still will be), font color and
> underline applied as direct formatting will be displayed in the TOC.

So, in the case of your colored headings, do not add color to the headings. Instead, change the Style so that the color is a part of the paragraph style. Then the color will not appear in your TOC or other references.

If you want some headings of the same level to be colored and some to not be colored, create a style based on the non-colored heading to apply where you want color, i.e., Heading 1 --> Heading 1 Colored. Then add the coloring to that style.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have scrambled my way to a solution. I do not understand why this method works and it is quite tidious, so I will leave the question open for other and better answers.

I noticed that - and I can't explain why - only text colouring is reverted on "Update field" while italic formatting is *not* reverted.

- Meaning, if I in the example above manually change the text colour of the cross-references from yellow to black, then when clicking "Update field" it changes back to yellow.
- But changing the text to **italic** will *remain* when clicking "Update field".

I thus tried making the text italic **and then right away back to normal, non-italic** and then changed the text colour manually to black.

This worked... Clicking "Update field" now does not revert the colour back to yellow. As if the italic-toggle made the program able to "remember" formatting changes from that moment on.

I haven't made a full investigation of other formatting types and any explanation would be very helpful. But at least this is a working method, albite quite "random".

Comment: This is not really an answer because it requires you to make changes to your TOC after each refresh. I would recommend editing your question and putting it at the end if you wish. See my response below.